# ntpdate cannot receive data

Tags: centos, time, ntp, ntpdate

I have a problem where running ntpdate on my server doesn't return any data therefore I get the following error:

```
[root@server etc]# ntpdate -d -u -v time.nist.gov 
12 Apr 01:10:09 ntpdate[32072]: ntpdate 4.2.2p1@1.1570-o Fri Nov 18 13:21:21 UTC 2011 (1)
Looking for host time.nist.gov and service ntp
host found : 24-56-178-141.co.warpdriveonline.com
transmit(24.56.178.141)
transmit(24.56.178.141)
transmit(24.56.178.141)
transmit(24.56.178.141)
transmit(24.56.178.141)
24.56.178.141: Server dropped: no data
server 24.56.178.141, port 123
stratum 0, precision 0, leap 00, trust 000
refid [24.56.178.141], delay 0.00000, dispersion 64.00000
transmitted 4, in filter 4
reference time:    00000000.00000000  Thu, Feb  7 2036 14:28:16.000
originate timestamp: 00000000.00000000  Thu, Feb  7 2036 14:28:16.000
transmit timestamp:  d3303975.1311947c  Thu, Apr 12 2012  1:10:13.074
filter delay:  0.00000  0.00000  0.00000  0.00000 
         0.00000  0.00000  0.00000  0.00000 
filter offset: 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000
         0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000
delay 0.00000, dispersion 64.00000
offset 0.000000

12 Apr 01:10:14 ntpdate[32072]: no server suitable for synchronization found
```

I have tried Googling the 'no server suitable for synchronization found' error online and I have tried disabling my firewall (running iptables -L returns no rules). I have also confirmed with my DC that there are no rules that are blocking ntp (port 123).

Does anyone have any ideas on how I may fix this?

Btw, this is what the output should look like on a working server in another DC:

```
11 Apr 19:01:24 ntpdate[725]: ntpdate 4.2.2p1@1.1570-o Fri Nov 18 13:21:17 UTC 2011 (1)
Looking for host 184.105.192.247 and service ntp
host found : 247.conarusp.net
transmit(184.105.192.247)
receive(184.105.192.247)
transmit(184.105.192.247)
receive(184.105.192.247)
transmit(184.105.192.247)
receive(184.105.192.247)
transmit(184.105.192.247)
receive(184.105.192.247)
transmit(184.105.192.247)
receive(184.105.192.247)
transmit(184.105.192.247)
server 184.105.192.247, port 123
stratum 2, precision -20, leap 00, trust 000
refid [184.105.192.247], delay 0.18044, dispersion 0.00006
transmitted 4, in filter 5
reference time:    d330364e.e956694f  Wed, Apr 11 2012 18:56:46.911
originate timestamp: d3303765.8702d025  Wed, Apr 11 2012 19:01:25.527
transmit timestamp:  d3303765.73b213e3  Wed, Apr 11 2012 19:01:25.451
filter delay:  0.18069  0.18044  0.18045  0.18048 
         0.18048  0.00000  0.00000  0.00000 
filter offset: -0.00195 -0.00197 -0.00211 -0.00202
         -0.00202 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000
delay 0.18044, dispersion 0.00006
offset -0.001970
```

Comment: The `time.nist.gov` is a globally distributed service. You may get different servers that provide different services from different locations. It's fine for NTP sync, but you should not expect to be able to do anything else, such as querying it directly.

Answer (score 2):

The `24.56.178.141` server refuses all non-authenticated requests - it won't respond to a normal query.

Instead of using the `time.nist.gov` DNS name, I'd recommend choosing a few geographically appropriate servers from NIST's [server list](http://tf.nist.gov/tf-cgi/servers.cgi).

Comment: Yes, I have tried that already. None of the ntp servers work.

Comment: What output do you get when you use a valid server?

Comment: Why NIST, and not pool.ntp.org?

Comment: @Zoredache Fair enough, I just stuck with the provider he's already using.. though the strata of some of the members of the pool can be problematic in certain scenarios.